# AttributeError: module 'pygmsh' has no attribute 'generate_mesh'

Tags: python, mesh

I am trying to execute the following code that creates a cube in mesh:

```
import pygmsh as pg
import numpy as np

def generate():
geom = pg.Geometry()
geom.add_box(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0.05)
return geom

if __name__ == '__main__':
import meshio
points, cells = pg.generate_mesh(generate())
meshio.write('cube.vtu', points, cells)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/200498/PycharmProjects/untitled/pygmsh.py", line 17, in 
<module>
points, cells = pg.generate_mesh(generate())
AttributeError: module 'pygmsh' has no attribute 'generate_mesh'
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You've called your own script "pygmsh", so it's hiding the library you installed. Rename your file to something else.

Comment: I renamed it now getting the following error:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/200498/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/cube.py", line 17, in <module>
    points, cells = pg.generate_mesh(generate())
  File "C:/Users/200498/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/cube.py", line 7, in generate
    geom = pg.Geometry()
AttributeError: module 'pygmsh' has no attribute 'Geometry'

Comment: Well, according to [the docs](https://github.com/nschloe/pygmsh/blob/master/README.md), it should be `pg.built_in.Geometry()`.

Comment: now run, but giving another error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/200498/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/cube.py", line 17, in <module>
    points, cells = pg.generate_mesh(generate())
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pygmsh\helpers.py", line 117, in generate_mesh
    gmsh_major_version = get_gmsh_major_version(gmsh_executable)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pygmsh\helpers.py", line 81, in get_gmsh_major_version
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT
.....FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado